# Is there a way to keep multiple lines when printing to a .txt file in python?

Tags: python

The original code looks like this:

```
for i in top_k:
   print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]))
```

I modified the code to this:

```
for i in top_k:
    outputFile = open('output.txt', 'w')
    print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]), file = outputFile)
    outputFile.close()
```

The original code works great since it's printing line by line in the console. But the modified code only prints the last to come from the loop to a .txt file. From what I can tell, it's replacing the text each time the loop runs, so the first text is replaced with the second text, and so forth.

Comment: In every iteration of the loop, you're executing `open('output.txt', 'w')`, so the file gets overwritten every time. Either open it with `'a'` or move the `open()` outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is using `a` mode to append the file.

```
outputFile = open('output.txt', 'a')
for i in top_k:
    print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]), file = outputFile)
outputFile.close()
```

However, I would recommend you to use pythonic way to append the file line by line using `with`.

```
with open("output.txt", "a") as outputFile :
    for i in top_k:
        outputFile.write(template.format(labels[i], results[i]), "\n")
```

Comment: I had to remove the "\n" argument to make this work. I'm assuming that was intended to create a new line after each iteration?

Comment: If that’s so, I would suggest you to use `print()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `'a'` as the argument to `open` instead of `'w'`. It appends rather than overwrites the file.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening your file with `w` mode which opens and "truncates" the file first, as you can see from the docs for the builtin [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). This means that it starts writing from the start of the file rather than the end. If you want to "append" the text, you should use `a` instead.

```py
outputFile = open('output.txt', 'a')
```

Additionally you do not want to be opening and closing the file for each iteration, as that task can be expensive and cause a hit to performance. I'd suggest using [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) to manage the file context.

```py
with open('output.txt', a):
    for i in top_k:
        print(template.format(labels[i], results[i]), file = outputFile)
```